# Populate TextViews and Buttons from SQLite in Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview

I'm new in Android development, and I am confused on how to display data dynamically...

I have a RelativeLayout activity type, where are 3 Textviews, 3 buttons and a ImageView.

What I want to achieve is to dynamically fill these items with the SQLite database.

Suppose that I do a query and I got 3 rows, then it should have all the structure I mentioned above but repeated 3 times with their respective data.

As a custom list?

In the documentation I've seen, many do not take the data from a database, but a StringArray, others take the data from the database but displayed in a list ...

Visually the structure is something like this:

[image: My Layout]

For now, the image will always be the blond woman...
But I want to fill at least the TextViews.
In the sense that if the query I got 2 rows, then you should see something like

[image: Layout changed]

**They would be so kind to explain in what way I can accomplish this?**

Comment: You can find a tutorial here about how to populate a Custom ListView with data retrieved from SQLite Database : 
http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/android/android-sqlite-database-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ListView is the best option for this situation, you just need to make your own custom adapter for listview.

Also make your data structure for data and put them in a list and send it to Adapter, then handle it in getView() method in adapter.

Create a list item layout which contains buttons, imageview and textviews and use it in custom adapter.

```
class MyData{
   String someText;
   String someText2;
   String buttonText;
}

List<MyData> list = new ArrayList<MyData>();

public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

   public MyAdapter(Context c, List<MyData> list){
   }


   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       // inflate your custom list item layout and put your data
   }
}
```

A sample [here](http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92)

Comment: Thanks, I think that what you wrote will serve me very much!
But one more thing,
Is difficult to adapt this into a Expandable List?

Comment: the idea is same for adapter list as well but you need to extends BaseExpandableListAdapter for that.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of ways to do this, but you probably want a ListView, with a CursorAdapter. The CursorAdaptertakes a Cursor as an input, and shows how an individual row looks. The CursorAdapterwould look something like this:

```
private class SpecialCursorAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public SpecialCursorAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);
        //Any other major setup needs to happen here.
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View v, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        //Take the view as given in newView, and populate it with the dat afrom cursor.
    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LinearLayout row = (LinearLayout) mInflater.inflate(
                R.layout.data_row, parent, false);
        //Inflate the row
        return row;
    }

}
```

The Cursor is populated with a standard query, there's plenty of resources how to do that. You get the ListView pointer from the inflated XML code, and do this:

```
ListView listvew=...;
Cursor cursoer=...;
SpecialCursorAdapter adapter=new SpecialCursorAdapter(this,cursor,0);
listview.setAdpater(adapater);
```

I regularly use this for very large data sets like this, and it works quite well.

Comment: As I said earlier, I'm new to Android, can you please give me some link where explain what you mean?

Comment: You can find a tutorial here about how to populate a ListView with data retrieved from SQLite Database. : 
http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/android/android-sqlite-database-example/